# text clustering in python other than using k_means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, k-means

Since k_means in sklearn only uses Euclidean distance, which isn't a good measurement for "distances" or "similarity" among texts, are there any alternatives in python we can use to do 'text clustering'?

Comment: You can use any of the clustering methods implemented in scikit-learn, see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) . For instance, you can use [hierarchical clustering algorithms](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#hierarchical-clustering)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use other metrics, [K-Medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) might be a good option. It is similar to K-Means, but uses the median, instead of the mean, in it's update step. This allows the use of arbitrary distance metrics.

A nice and easy to use implementation is available in [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/5085) scikit-learn pull request.